# Jquery Nested pannel overlapping above content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Im using the jquery lib: http://suprb.com/apps/nested/ to create a pannel that displays some content in a mini seamless grid, but for some reason no matter what I try the grid decides it want to jump up and overlap the "familiars box" above as shown in the img below:

[image]

As you can see the grid boxs are literally hopping out of their own div panel and placing themselves above.When I inspect one of the grid items i notice that they are each being positioned absolutely, besides that im using bootstrap and also using a Macbook pro retina ( idk if the resolution could be throwing it off possibly)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is more than 3 months after the fact, but I was having the same issue and wanted to share my resolution  - There is a fix here:  https://github.com/r9k/Nested/commit/d6f97b7ef565a7e715c4c87f73a45037f83a73ae

There was a typo in one of the for loops that prevented some cells from being flagged as "used" - the erroneous loop initializes the counter to 'col' rather than 'row' (this is in the _renderGrid function).

Broken:

```
for (var y = col; y >= 0; y--)
```

Fixed:

```
for (var y = row; y >= 0; y--)
```

Comment: I've changed this line in mine, and it doesn't seem to affect it at all. My issue is it ignoring margin-bottom, and therefor pressing everything right up against each other way toooo close.